# How to prevent children component from rerendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

My searchbar component changes state of Layout component. Therefore, Layout component triggres rerendering of all its childs components. I tried to implement React.memo(), but it didn't help me. Please correct me. Thank you in advance!

Layout component:

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
    state = {
        cityName: "",
        date: "",
        icon: "",
    };

    searchbarSubmitHandler = e => {
        const cityName =
            e.target.children[0].firstChild.children[0].value;
        this.setState({
            cityName: cityName
        });
        console.log(this.state.cityName);
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    searchbarChangeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({
            cityName: e.target.value
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Searchbar
                    submit={this.searchbarSubmitHandler}
                    change={this.searchbarChangeHandler}
                />
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        component={() =>
                            <CurrentWeather icon={this.state.icon} />
                        }
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/24h-weather"
                        component={HourlyWeather}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

searchbar component:

```
const searchbar = props => {
    return (
        <div className="searchbar">
            <form onSubmit={props.submit}>
                <div className="inputs">
                    <div className="inputTextWrapper">
                        <input
                            className="inputText"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="City name..."
                            onChange={props.change}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <input
                        className="inputSubmit"
                        type="submit"
                        value="Search"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default searchbar;
```

CurrentWeather component which I want to not rerender:

```
const currentWeather = props => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3>London, UK</h3>
            <img
              src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.icon}.png`}
              alt="weather icon"
            />
        </div>
    );
};

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps === nextProps;

export default React.memo(currentWeather, areEqual);
```

Comment: can you make a codepen to this? I suggest to separate the switch in router component, and give more informative name to the functions.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    component={() => <CurrentWeather icon={this.state.icon} />}
    />
```

The way that `component` works is "router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. The existing component is unmounted and the new component is mounted instead of just updating the existing component"

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#component

If you change this to `render`, you will not get this effect, and it won't recreate this component.

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => <CurrentWeather icon={this.state.icon} />}
    />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-hill-2ykhq to show this working

Comment: Your solution worked for me! I learned a lot. Thank you! Actually, I didn't expect such prompt responses 

Comment: Also, I changed my export default of child component from this "export default Home;" to this "export default React.memo(Home);"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the `props` argument passed to `CurrentWeather` is an object, and thus your `React.memo` second argument (`areEqual`) checks for object equality.
Two props objects passed during different renders won't be strictly equal, or even shallowly so, because they refer to different locations in memory - and so, `prevProps === nextProps` will always return false.

You might want to refactor `areEqual` into something like:

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.icon === nextProps.icon;
```

Assuming that the `icon` prop is the only prop that changes, or whose change we care about, in the props passed to `CurrentWeather`.

Comment: This is not correct, the only prop being passed to CurrentWeather  is `icon` which is a string.  React.Memo will do a shallow comparison which will include`icon` prop.

Comment: The only prop being passed to CurrentWeather may be `icon`, but CurrentWeather is still passed a `props` object - and the implementation of `areEqual` present in the question compares the previous and next `props` objects, not the `icon` prop specifically. Shallow comparison of objects is still a reference check, which will then return `false` every time.

Comment: Ahh I see where you are coming from.  The fact his own created equality check wasn't correct.  In that case, not invoking his own equality check would have worked

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to store the icon in the state of the parent component, but in the child component as this cuts the dependency. If you need to set it from the parent, check out the answer above form udi